# Reducing multichannel audio noise with Speex

Tags: audio, audio-recording, speex, noise-reduction

I've been searching high and low for an example on how to use the Speex library's preprocessor for multichannel audio.

The documentation for `speex_preprocess_state_init()` says that:

> Creates a new preprocessing state. You MUST create one state per channel processed.

I assume that means I need to call `speex_preprocess_run()` on each channel separately, but won't that potentially "skew" the result if the preprocessor happens to remove more noise from one channel than the other?

Also, `speex_preprocess_run()` indicates whether the audio is considered voice or noise/silence. If I have to call the function for each channel, what happens if one channel is considered voice and the other isn't?

Am I overthinking this?

Comment: How many channels?  If you are simply talking about voice recorded in stereo, why not mix down to mono first?  If you are talking about many channels with likely separate voices on each, treating them independently may be what you want anyway.

Comment: Yeah, just talking about voice recorded in stereo, so 2 channels. Maybe I'm being retarded, but won't I lose fidelity if I downmix to mono?

Comment: Try it and see.  You'll find that for voice, it will be fine.  Sometimes there are phasing problems depending on how the mics were set up, but that's rare, and won't generally impact whether or not voice is detectable.

Comment: Interesting. So, you're saying that using mono audio for a voice application, such as Mumble or Skype, is generally just fine?

Comment: Absolutely.  Your voice is in mono, after all.  If you're wondering why speakerphones and some laptops have an array of microphones, it's for noise and feedback reduction.  Based on the phase delay between microphones, a hardware DSP can more easily determine what the wanted signal is vs the noise.  That's not something you can (or should) do in software without knowing specific parameters of microphones, and licensing some shanzzy algorithms.

Comment: Well, awesome! Thanks a ton for the quick replies!

Comment: No problem.  I'll summarize as an answer for other folks looking at this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voices recorded in stereo typically mix down to mono without trouble.  Microphone placement can cause some phasing issues, but that generally isn't an issue.

Once you mix down to mono,  you can process the audio as normal.

Alternatively, you can pick one of the channels, and ignore the second.  This might not be as reliable though, as the voice might have been off-axis when recorded.